# .net core throw badrequest from repository

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, exception, bad-request

At the moment in the repositories there are some ArgumentException's being thrown, i.e. when a selected code is already in use.

```
public DM.Category Add(DM.Category category)
    {
        if (_context.Categories.Any(x => x.Code == category.Code))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Category code '{category.Code}' already in use");
        }

        return _context.Categories.Add(category).Entity;
    }
```

Now if this would happen, all the user would see in console is a 500. How could I throw this error neatly to the UI (angular) / what would be best practise?

I looked at

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult test(Option option)
{
    return BadRequest("Error message here");
}
```

But I can't get that to work inside my Repository (which is inheriting from BaseRepository).

Comment: why not to throw `BadRequest` from repository directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core have provided **ProblemDetails** class and **ValidationProblemDetails** to handle details of an error with an HTTP Response based on RFC 7807

You can read the spec here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807

In your case, you might want to create a middleware that capture your custom exception and return ProblemDetails

it will be something lik this

```
public class CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly IHostEnvironment host;

        public CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostEnvironment host)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.host = host;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var body = context.Response.StatusCode;
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }

        private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            var problemDetail = new ProblemDetails()
            {
                Title = exception.Message,
                Detail = exception.StackTrace,
                Instance = context.Request.Path,
                Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            };

            // for security reason, not leaking any implementation/error detail in production
            if (host.IsProduction())
            {
                problemDetail.Detail = "Unexpected error occured";
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            context.Response.ContentType = "applications/problem+json";

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(problemDetail));
        }
    }
```